# mod_perl share variables across child processes

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I have a mod_perl system accepting API calls from different client systems
Suppose in the child perl program I have calls like this which does some heavy processing

```
$conf{$client_id} = generate_client_conf($client_id); # returns a ref to a hash
```

I would like to re-use this variable $conf{$client_id} in other child processes
How can I do this ?

The variables cannot be loaded at startup.pl ,but needs to be cached once it is generated

Comment: You may want to look at `memcached` and associated Perl modules. This is not a strict answer to your problem (memcached is a separate process, not caching inside Apache), but may well solve your performance issue.

Comment: Memcached , means I will have to make a TCP connection everytime in the mod_perl script. 
I am not able to persist the Memcached handle too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Cache::FastMmap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache%3a%3aFastMmap)

> In mod_perl, just open the cache at the global level in the
>   appropriate module,  which is executed as the server is starting and
>   before it starts forking children,  but you'll probably want to chmod
>   or chown the file to the permissions  of the apache process.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I'm trying to use Cache::FastMmap in mod_perl. It isn't clear how to initialize it. If I create it in startup.pl it complains that the code can't work in threads. If I then just create an empty file (to use as the shared memory file) in startup.pl that also doesn't work. So is there a concrete example of using Cache::FastMmap with mod_perl (version 2 and with Apache 2.4)? Thanks.